# what does "\S" equal in Regex?

Tags: regex

What does "\S" equal  in Regex?

I have a regex:

```
/<((?:https?\:\/\/)*(?:[^\/?#])\/*\S*)>/ig;
```

trying to match:

What does \S equal? e.g.: [\w\d?:"-_]

Comment: I'd be *very* curious to hear an explanation from whoever nominated this for reopening. I can't imagine what the case for reopening would be.

Answer (score 3):

`\S` matches anything **except** whitespace.

Regard as the opposite of `\s` (which matches whitespace).

(Personally I find `\S` obfuscating for this reason, particularly when viewing in some fonts where S and s look too similar. I prefer `[^\s]`).

Answer (score 0):

\S means "Non-whitespace characters".

See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression)

Comment: Actually, it means "any one character that's not a whitespace character".  The phrase "no whitespaces" is so ambiguous, it's impossible to tell what you meant by it.